# Cant remove language from router in Next.js using ni18n

Tags: typescript, next.js, localization, i18next, react-i18next

I am trying to develop a website using ni18n on Next.js, but I cannot remove the language part from the url even if i force remove it.

I want it to look like this.

"http://localhost:3000"

But when I try to type it the website it routes to "localhost:3000/tr".

Any idea on why is this happening. I cant seem to figure out it.

```
//_app.tsx
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppPropsWithLayout) {
  // Use the layout defined at the page level, if available
  const getLayout = Component.getLayout ?? ((page) => page)
  
  if(typeof window !== 'undefined'){
    const locale = window.localStorage.getItem('locale') || 'en'
    useSyncLanguage(locale)
  }
  
  
  return getLayout(
      <ThemeProvider attribute='class'>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </ThemeProvider>
  )
}
```

```
// ni18n.config.ts
import type { Ni18nOptions } from 'ni18n'

export const ni18nConfig: Ni18nOptions = {
  supportedLngs: ['en', 'tr'],
  ns: ['common','navbar'],
}
```

```
//18next.d.ts
declare module 'react-i18next' {
  interface CustomTypeOptions {
    resources: {
        common: typeof common,
        navbar: typeof navbar
    }
  }
}
```

```
//next.config.js
module.exports = {
    i18n: {
      defaultLocale: 'en',
      locales: ['en', 'tr'],
    },
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

After quite a lot of head scratching i finally figured out why this happens. This is due to 'localeDetection' setting being 'true' by default in 18next. It can be fixed by simply turning this setting of in the config file.

```
module.exports = {
  i18n: {
    ...
    localeDetection: false,
  },
}
```